# How can I add exclusions to Windows Defender, but first find out if their is another antivirus on the computer?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that will add exclusions to Windows Defender. I use

```
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Users\ME\Desktop"
```

to add the exclusions, but if there is another antivirus other than Windows Defender on the computer then PowerShell will give me an error. I need to be able to catch the error and then have a popup window stating that there is another antivirus already installed.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a [`try{}catch{}` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  It's odd that another antivirus would interfere with your ability to add exclusions to Windows Defender...

Comment: My guess is that the Windows defender must be running and because another Antivirus is installed, service is disabled so you would have to check if the Defender service is running. I only have defender right now though so I cannot replicate this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it is Windows 10 so if there is another antivirus installed then Windows Defender is automatically disabled completely until the other antivirus is removed

Comment: yes @MathiasR.Jessen, I tried a `try{}catch{}` statement but that will work for any error that happens, I only want it to catch the "another antivirus installed already" error only

Comment: Inspect the error inside the catch block, if it's the error you're looking for show the warning, otherwise rethrow the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself. I wrote:

```
$AV = Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Class AntiVirusProduct
$installedAV = $AV | Where-Object {$_.displayName -notlike "Windows Defender"}
$otherAV = $AV | Where-Object {$_.displayName -ne "Windows Defender"}

if ($otherAV) {

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Another AV is installed: $($installedAV.displayName)",0,"Error!",16)

}else{

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Only Windows Defender is installed as your AV.",0,"Passed",0)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching an error, you could precheck if another antivirus program is installed and active.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace “root\SecurityCenter2” -Class AntiVirusProduct
```

You can convert the returned product state to hex and split it into 3 byte blocks to check the [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432509(v=vs.85).aspx) (first byte block), state (second byte block) and if it is up to date (third byte block).

```
('{0:X6}' -f $productState).Substring(2, 2) # 10 should be product is active
('{0:X6}' -f $productState).Substring(4, 2) # 00 should be up to date
```

See following code as example:

```
$AV = Get-CimInstance -Namespace “root\SecurityCenter2” -Class AntiVirusProduct
$WD = $AV | Where-Object {$_.displayName -like "Windows Defender"}
$installedAV = $AV | Where-Object {$_.displayName -notlike "Windows Defender"}
$productState = [int]('{0:X6}' -f $WD.productState).Substring(2, 2)
if ($productState -eq 10) {
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
    Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Users\ME\Desktop"
} else {
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("Another AV is installed: $($installedAV.displayName)", 0, "", 0x10)
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand. So then how can I make it that the script will first check if there is ANY antivirus (other than Windows Defender) installed on the computer and then show popup message and terminate the rest of the script if there is?

Comment: @M.Simon I have added an example.

Comment: Perfect! But can I also make a pop-up msg asking "Would you like to uninstall the antivirus so you can continue with the exclusions? If yes click yes otherwise click no." and uninstall the other AV if yes is clicked and then continue with the exclusions after?

Comment: Bummer. I tried to run the script (your example) on a computer with another AV and it did fine (it said "Another AV is installed: ___" and it said the installed AV), but when I ran the script on a a computer (Windows 8.1) with only Windows Defender it just said "Another AV is installed:" that's it, and the exclusions did execute. As if the `if` statement was never there...

Comment: And it seems that when I run `Get-CimInstance -Namespace “root\SecurityCenter2” -Class AntiVirusProduct` then the `productState` is never `10` its different from every version of Windows Defender (I think). So I tried `if ($AV | Where-Object {$_.displayName -eq "Windows Defender"})` but that still went straight to the `else` statement. Any ideas?